# Текст, введенный в форме вывести на странице

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Каким образом можно сделать, чтоб текст, который пользователь вводит в форме, сразу же появляется над формой. 
Это что-то типа пример, как будет выглядеть текст.

Желательно ссылку на пример подобного.
Благодарю за внимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если используете `jQuery` можно сделать например так:

```
<div class="text"></div>

<form>
  <input type="text">
</form>

<script>
    var userText;
    var $textDiv = $('.text');
    var $input = $('input');

    $('input').on('input', function() {
        userText = $input.val();
        $textDiv.html(userText);
    });
</script>
```

Учтите, что событие `input` не работает в старых IE
[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/2fdmv7vg/)

**UPD**
[Пример](https://jsfiddle.net/2fdmv7vg/1/) для нескольких полей.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо. Подскажите пожалуйста еще, если 2 формы ввода сделать, то как тогда должен выглядеть код?

Comment: @Денис Если я вас правильно понял, то обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
<form action="" id="form">
    <textarea name="" id="text" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <div id="preview"></div>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function myFunc(){
    var input = $("#text").val();
    $("#preview").html(input);
}       
myFunc();

$('#text').keyup(function(){
    myFunc();
});
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q9s802yo/2/

Comment: `keyup` плох тем, что в поле текст можно вставить правой кнопкой мыши.

Answer (score 1):

ID должны быть названы как имена формы

HTML:

```
<div class="form-data">
        Name:<span id="name"></span>
        Age:<span id="age"></span>
    </div>
    <form action="/" name="form">

        <input type="text" name="name">

        <input type="text" name="age">

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">

    </form>
```

JavaScript:

```
var form = document.forms['form'];
        var formElements = form.elements;

        for (var i = formElements.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            formElements[i].addEventListener('keyup', function() {
                document.querySelector('#' + this.name).textContent = this.value;
            })
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: `keyup` плох тем, что в поле текст можно вставить правой кнопкой мыши.

Comment: В принципе да ну если на чистом javascript то можно еще обработчик повесить